# How do I identify the cause of GNOME crashing in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm having repeated random crashes of GNOME on Ubuntu 20.04 which cause me to be logged out. Each time I log in, I choose Ubuntu on Wayland to deal with the issue I was experiencing in an [earlier post](https://superuser.com/questions/1669089/why-is-gnome-crashing-when-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-vm/1669729). I have not yet been able to tie today's crashing to any particular application, though I suspect VMWare Workstation. Where are the logs I need to check and what should I be looking for within those logs? The crashes are happening every 15-60 minutes.

Comment: Did you even *try* to search for this?  [Viewing System Logs](/https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/viewing-linux-logs-command-line/) .. [Journalctl to View and Manipulate Systemd Logs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs).  You have two systems at play here.  One is the tradition ASCII text log, the other is a logging mechanism (called journald) used by services.  Finding the cause of a problem like this is a PITA but can be done with a little creativity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by downgrading VMWare Workstation on my host from 16.2.0 to 16.1.2.

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Workstation-16-2-0-cannot-use-paste/m-p/2875395